# File Upload Option in Automation Testing Using Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

I need to test a particular scenario where I need to upload a file from any folder from my local machine and check whether it gets uploaded correctly as that of below image. I am writing automation testing script using Robot Framework to test in Chrome browser

[image]

I am trying to use Choose File Keyword which is normally used for this scenario.

```
Test8 To upload a file from Local Drive
Open Browser   http://localhost:35234/    chrome
Select From List By Index            ${transmission drop down}            0
Choose File    ${upload click1}    ${CURDIR}${/}SampleFiles${/}Test.txt
```

First Line opens my application locally.
Second line selects File Upload option from drop down.
`${transmission drop down}` holds the ID of the drop down.

Then I am using `Choose File` Option. `${upload click1}` option holds the xpath value of `Add Document` button And Test.txt file is available in the corresponding folder provided.

I am not sure where I am going wrong, but I am getting a strange webdriver error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: cannot focus element\n  
(Session info: chrome=45.0.2454.93)\n  (Driver info:chromedriver=2.15.322448 
(52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 
x86_64)'
```

I am able to run other tests without this strange error.I am not sure whether the Choose File has right parameters. Am I going wrong anywhere? It would be great if someone could help me by providing sample Test Case.

Comment: that error seems pretty clear to me?  You're unable to focus on an element on the screen and therefore should try and identify it differently?  Also, I'm not sure if this matters but you're using forward slash instead of backslash to get to the text file

Comment: @shicky: forward slashes work on every major platform, including windows.

Answer (score 1):

You say that `${upload click1}` has the xpath to an "add document" button. The locator for `Choose File` needs to be to an `<input>` element on the page, not a button.

Comment: This is precisely it. But what i find disturbing is the documentation mentioned nothing about this.

Comment: @Mack: where do you get your documentation?