# Upload a file in browser using Robot Framework Test

Tags: selenium, pycharm, robotframework, filechooser, selenium2library

I'm writing Test Cases using **Robot Framework** and **Selenium** for my Web application. I tried to Upload a file, but I can't its failing.

My Code is

```
*** Variables ***
${TVAURL}     http://localhost:1500/
${Browser}    Firefox

TC_01: Enter into the application
    [Documentation]   Enter into the application to upload a file
    Open Browser   ${TVAURL}     ${Browser}
    maximize browser window
    Choose File ........
```

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload File</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to know how to use this **`Choose File`** for this file upload test. I don't know how to do this. I need to upload a file automatically without any third party tools like Autoit, etc.,

I referred the following http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Choose%20File

Moreover I referred the following questions too

- [File Upload Option in Automation Testing Using Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620136/file-upload-option-in-automation-testing-using-robot-framework)
- https://github.com/robotframework/OldSeleniumLibrary/issues/108

But I can't get any solutions. Kindly assist me how to do this using Robot Framework, Selenium in Pycharm Studio.

**Reply for Answer #1: @demouser123**

Still I'm having issue, here with I have attached the Screen shot

[image]

It always opens the Desktop, and fails. Kindly assist me.

I trided the following code

```
*** Variables ***
${PO_AddShell}     //*[@id="fileToUpload"]

click button  ${PO_AddShell}
Choose File   ${PO_AddShell}    E://Project/Publish/SampleTest.1500/rose.jpg
```

Comment: Please specify the error when you say "it's failing".

Comment: @demouser123 - I don't know how to specify the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation given in the Selenium2library, the syntax to use  use the `Choose File` keyword is

```
Choose File  Locator  File_name
```

For a dialog or input that WebDriver can interact with the example would do  something like this

```
Choose File id=fileToUpload  C://Downloads/Demo/Abc.txt
```

Here `C://Downloads/Demo/Abc.txt` is the location on the system where the file is kept. Change this to your own file location.

Also, I remember this solution also, which ultimately worked for me too - [SO Post about uploading from a Windows directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183182/how-to-upload-file-from-windows-directory-using-selenium2library-and-robot-frame). You can also try this one.

Comment: Its opening the file open dialog but its not selecting the file and not clicking the Open button.

Comment: what is the path and the locator used by you?

Comment: `Choose File    xpath=.//div/input     .${CURDIR}\rose.jpg`

Comment: The said picture is exist in the hosted root (i.e., `http://localhost:1500/rose.jpg`) - Its always opens the desktop and its not hitting the Open button automatically.

Comment: I getting the following error too `Element locator 'xpath=.//div/input'` did not match any elements.`

Comment: The locator that I have mentioned `.//div/input` is a dummy locator. You need to use the locator that you are getting on your webpage. Please us that locator.

Comment: I can't able to get you, that file browser is a default feature of the browser how could I get the locator from that. Could you please help me. I updated the question with a sample HTML.

Comment: Your path needs to be `E://Project/Publish/SampleTest.1500/rose.jpg`. The file browser is opening which means that the Close File Command and the locator are correct. You need to give the correct file location and it would work.

Comment: yes, I trided the both version `E://Project/Publish/SampleTest.1500/rose.jpg` and `E://Project/Publish/SampleTest.1500/rose.jpge`. But its failing to locate the file, its opening the Desktop. Kindly see dialog box in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, not its working `E:\\Project\\Publish\\SampleTest.1500\\rose.jpg`. But the file browser is not closing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146855/discussion-between-demouser123-and-mastero).

Comment: Hello @Mastero , There are two ways you can solve this issue , one is by going with choose file and selecting the image/file . The other way is set your browser download preferences to your filepath and use sikuli to select the image. Sikuli is nice library if you want to interact with GUI , you can capture a screenshot and use click method. Please let me know if you are still stuck with issue

Comment: I need solution for the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626501/webdriverexception-message-file-not-found-close-upload-file-window-in-robot Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0):

## I am providing alternate solution for the question. Please try this if you didnt get.

Prerequisite for running below script :

Install Sikulix on your machine from this [SikuliX](https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download) ,this is easy to install and install robotframework-SikuliLibrary . You can explore the documentation if you want some more options [SikuliX documentation](http://rainmanwy.github.io/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/doc/SikuliLibrary.html). Capture the images like download path/filename using some snipping tool and update the name in the following script.

```
*** Settings ***
Library          Selenium2Library
Library           SikuliLibrary

*** Test cases  ***
Login to Browser with download preferences
 [Documentation]   This one is without specifying download location
    Open Browser  https://www.docdroid.net/   Chrome
    Click Element   id=selectFiles
    Sleep   5
    SikuliLibrary.Click      /images/download.PNG
    SikuliLibrary.Click      /images/file.PNG
    SikuliLibrary.Click      /images/open.PNG
```

If you want to specify download location , go with below script

```
*** Settings ***

    Library          Selenium2Library
    Library           SikuliLibrary

    *** Test cases  ***
    Login to Browser with download preferences
     [Documentation]   You can specify your download location
        Open Browser  https://www.docdroid.net/   Chrome
        Click Element   id=selectFiles
        Sleep   5
        SikuliLibrary.Input Text           /images/file_path.PNG     C:\\Users\\Madhu\\Downloads
        Press Special Key        ENTER
        #SikuliLibrary.Click      /images/download.PNG
        SikuliLibrary.Click      /images/file.PNG
        SikuliLibrary.Click      /images/open.PNG
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm in weekend, so I will test this code on coming Monday...

Comment: Sikuli is a working solution for limited local testing, but it will not work using headless browser (phantoms, chrome in headless mode), nor remote selenium - selenium hub, or the cloud's browserstack,  sauce labs, etc. Thus I would not recommend setting this hard dependency in the tests.

Comment: Thanks @Todor.. I am not aware of this.. is there any alternate option if I want to use sikuli in headless mode..

Comment: Nope, none that I'm aware of; that's the point of the "headless" - there's no UI to interact with, nothing for a person/sikuli to click or send keystrokes to :). Thus using RF's native `Choose File` is usually the way to go - what it actually does is sending through SE the path as keys to the input field. Which, on the other hand has issues with html5 fancy js uploaders - but that's another topic :)

Comment: OK Thanks for providing info.

Comment: But it's not the headless mode - rather the remote selenium execution, that is the main driving force for loose copling of tests with the actual operation (the upload in this case). At a certain point the quantity of the cases for the SUT will be too high for serial execution, and you would want to parallelize it (my current UI tests take 40+ hours if ran in serial...). Also with remote exec you  easily have mixed browser coverage - osx + safari and win10 + opera for example. This in fact is the main driver for selenium hub, correspondingly all cloud solutions based on it.

Comment: Sorry if these comments sound like a lecture, looks like I'm in that mood :D

Answer (score 0):

using autoit library in robotframework, you can upload a file into application. This solution works even the system is locked.

Input Filename and click send in Window dialog

```
run keyword if  '${Browser}' == 'Chrome'  File upload in Chrome browser
...   ELSE IF  '${Browser}' == 'Firefox'  File upload in Firefox browser
```

---

File upload in Chrome browser

```
control focus  [CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]  ${EMPTY}  [CLASSNN:Edit1]
control send  [CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]  ${EMPTY}  [CLASSNN:Edit1]  C:\\File_Upload\\Test_Upload
control click  [CLASS:#32770; TITLE:Open]  ${EMPTY}  &Open
```

---

File upload in Firefox browser

```
control focus  File Upload  ${EMPTY}  [CLASSNN:Edit1]
control send  File Upload  ${EMPTY}  [CLASSNN:Edit1]  C:\\File_Upload\\Test_Upload
control click  File Upload  ${EMPTY}  &Open
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use

```
click button  ${PO_AddShell}
```

Just use choose file without clicking

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to use the Choose File keyword
Choose File  Locator  File_name
This keyword work fine for locator `type=file` so try to use locator `=//input[@type="file"]`