# WebDriverException: Message: File not found - Close Upload FIle window in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

I need to close the File Upload window of a browser. I tried the following code to achieve this

**`Press Key    id=fileToUpload    \\27`** - I found the ascii character in the URL http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html

My Complete code is

```
*** Variables ***
${TVAURL}     http://localhost:1500/
${Browser}    Firefox

TC_01: Enter into the application
    [Documentation]   Enter into the application to upload a file
    Open Browser   ${TVAURL}     ${Browser}
    Choose File    id=fileToUpload    C://Downloads/Demo/rose.png
    Press Key    id=fileToUpload    \\27
```

My respective sample HTML code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload File</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

It gives the error message **`WebDriverException: Message: File not found : //27`**

[image]

I need to close the file uploader window of a browser, once the file gets uploaded (i.e., next to the `Choose File` command)

[image]

Comment: Please mention your test bed.

Comment: @demouser123 Once file get uploaded I need to close the window not on submit button click event.

Comment: Your test bed means your system configuration - what is your Selenium, FF version? I think the `\\27` you are using to escape would not work here. Also, the file will only get uploaded when you submit the file for uploading, which is when you press either Enter or Click on the OK button. Why are you pressing an Esc key, instead of using Enter.

Comment: @demouser123 - Yes I'm trying for Key press escape

Comment: @demouser123 - The version of Selenium is 3.4.3 and Firefox is 53.0.3 (32-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Once you upload the file you need to click the submit button on the website and not uploadfile again with the wrong locator..

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

Change your last line from:

Press Key    id=fileToUpload
to

Press Key   name=submit

That should do it for you.

Comment: Before pressing the submit button I need to close the window.

Comment: You are doing this the wrong way if you want to do it with selenium...have a look at this [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test)

Comment: You should not be opening the OS file upload. Selenium will do that for you if you send the path to the file to the corrent locator. If you need to interact with the OS then you need a different tool such as AUTOIT and you will need to call that from your script. Hope this helps.